# Angular AoT Compilation with Sass styles and pug (jade) templates

Tags: angular, sass, webpack, pug, angular2-aot

Did anyone find a solution to compile Angular (version >= 2) with Sass and pug in webpack?

Comment: Same problem here, i have aot + sass working, but i'm still compiling pug files to html (via pug cli) and use templateUrl reference to compiled html.

Comment: i know resolve for angular-cli (not for WebPack), AoT/JiT, Unit & E2E test - work, suitable for version 2 and above

Answer (score 0):

> Adding this to https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter in config/webpack.common.js module.rules
>   "        {
>             test: /.(pug|jade)$/,
>             use: ['pug-ng-html-loader']
>           }
>   "
>     plus in resolve.extensions I added ".pug"
>   and this in package.json devDependencies
>   '    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
>       "pug-ng-html-loader": "^1.0.10"
>   '
>   I can run .pug files with both the "build:aot" and "server:dev:hmr" scripts